# ajax jquery error shows [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this code is working properly in some pc 
i have basic ajax call to show batch list in select tag

```
function show_batch(class_id,batch_id){
    if(class_id){
        $.ajax({
            url:root_path+"module/fee_dtl/show_batch.php",
            data:"class_id="+class_id+"&batch_id="+batch_id,
            type:"post",
            success:function(e){
                $('#stu_batch').html(e);
                $('#stu_batch').removeAttr('disabled');
                search();
            },error(e){
                alert(e);
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('#stu_batch').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#stu_batch').html("<option value=''>Select Class First</option>");
        search();
    }
}
```

i was expecting list of batch in my stu_batch id select tag

```
<?php 
 session_start(); ?>
 <option value="">Select Batch</option>
 <?php 
 $phpfiles=glob("../../include/php/*.php");
 foreach ($phpfiles as $phpfile) {
     include_once($phpfile);
 }
 extract($_POST);
 $batch_data=fetchAll("select id,name from batch where class_id=$class_id");
 foreach ($batch_data as $batch_value) {
?>
    <option <?php if(isset($batch_id)&& $batch_id==$batch_value['id']){echo "selected";} ?> value="<?php echo $batch_value['id'];?>"><?php echo $batch_value['name'];?></option>
<?php
 }
```

?>
this is my show_batch.php file code

```
<td>Select Class                     
                    <select onchange="show_batch(this.value,'')"  class="form-control"  id="stu_class" name="class_id">
                    <option value="">Please Select Class</option>
                    <?php 
                        $class_data=fetchAll("select id,name from class");
                        foreach ($class_data as $class_value) {
                    ?>
                            <option <?php if((isset($_POST['class_id']) && $_POST['class_id']==$class_value['id']) || ($id && $class_fee_dtl['class_id']==$class_value['id'])){echo "selected";} ?> value="<?php echo $class_value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $class_value['name'] ?></option>
                        <?php }?>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td>Select Batch 
                    <select class="form-control" disabled onchange="search()" id="stu_batch"  name="batch">
                    <option value="">Select Class First</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
```

and these are my two. in second dropdown i want to show ajax list

Comment: By providing an object to `html()` you're effectively calling `toString()` on it - hence the output. You most likely need to loop through the response and manually update the HTML. If you want to debug this, use `console.log(e)` to see exactly what the structure of the response is

Comment: What happens if you change `$('#stu_batch').html(e);` to `$('#stu_batch').html(JSON.stringify(e));`?

Comment: nothing different same result

Comment: add the php code, I want to check that what you code there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return some result from your php code

```
 session_start();
 $phpfiles=glob("../../include/php/*.php");
 foreach ($phpfiles as $phpfile) {
     include_once($phpfile);
 }
 extract($_POST);
 $batch_data=fetchAll("select id,name from batch where class_id=$class_id");
 $finalHtml = '<option value="">Select Batch</option>';
 foreach ($batch_data as $batch_value) {
    $selected = (isset($batch_id) && $batch_id == $batch_value['id']) ? 'seelcted' : '';
    $finalHtml .= '<option selected="'.$selected.'" value="'.$batch_value['id'].'" />'.$batch_value['name'].'</option>';
 }
 echo $finalHtml;
```

Also in your Jquery code you need to append the options

```
$('#stu_batch')
.find('option')
.empty()
.append(response);
```

Comment: its not even showing my first option which is <option>Select page</option> even if i erase remain code from show_batch and i am echoing my $result as well and i think its not calling child page. this code is working properly in my laptop but not in my client laptop

Comment: Now check the response in console before append

Comment: POST http://loclahost/synthesis/module/fee_dtl/show_batch.php 0 () cosole showing me this

Comment: first add print_r($batch_data); exit; before foreach and then console the response console.log(e);

Comment: then your query is wrong it won't get any result, for demo you can replace this code on $batchAll,
$batch_id  = '2';
 $batch_data = [['id'=>'1','name'=>'First Batch'],['id'=>'2','name'=>'Secound Batch']];

Comment: Have you check the network tab of your browser while running the ajax?

Comment: Now run the same URL in the different tab?

Comment: Maaan, Your ajax URL in different tab?

Comment: did you get the same result in network tab if you change the class_id manually ? I mean via ajax

Comment: Now you need to remove the comments otherwise the comment list show long then question :P

Answer (score 0):

Do `console.log()` your Ajax result to check what its returning. then bind it to html.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the show_batch.php resultset, which is return after completing ajax call. It seems like it is returning an object and which are trying to populate as options into select tag.

One of the method is to return the result not as object instead try this in your show_batch.php file

```
$option = "";
$option .= "<option value='$val'>".$res."</option>";
echo $option;
exit;
```

Now inside ajax success function it will gets displayed. Please not that the above given code is just an example you need to modify it according to your need.

Comment: its not even showing my first option which is <option>Select page</option> even if i erase remain code from show_batch and i am echoing my $result as well and i think its not calling child page. this code is working properly in my laptop but not in my client laptop